# On local development environment font-icon (si-atelier) display perfectly, but on production server some thing missing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-ecommerce

On local development environment font-icon (si-atelier) display perfectly, but on production server icon not displayed on Chrome and mozilla but on on IE9.

- Wordpress Themes - Atelier
- Atelier Demo - http://atelier.swiftideas.com

I want those icon:
[image]
On my local server it perfect.

But when i upload in production server, there is the problem:

[image]

Mozilla and Chrome not showing that icon, but IE9 show that icon perfectly.i'm using a shared hosting.

the console show this problem, but i'm not understand. Think their is a font-face problem.

[image]

Thanks advance all for helping me.

Comment: The console says 404. That means not found. Have you uploaded the font to the directory it's looking for it in?

Comment: Yes, all the font pre uploaded with the themes.

Comment: And if you browse directly to the URL of the font... does your browser find it?

Comment: if i browes this address - http://www.v1.shatejbangla.com/wp-content/themes/atelier/css/font/si-shop-three.woff, then it's downloaded. But on this address - (http://www.v1.shatejbangla.com/wp-content/themes/atelier/css/font/si-shop-three.woff?-7oeevn) give 404 page

Comment: I have tested [your production website](http://www.v1.shatejbangla.com). The problem is coming from the `?-7oeevn` at the end of each called font. Without it it works. So you have to find out what is adding this at the end of each called font url.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your help :). Following your suggestion, i'm remove `?-7oeevn` and it's working fine. 
But their is a single problem.
`http://www.v1.shatejbangla.com/wp-content/themes/atelier/css/font/si-shop-three.ttf?-7oeevn Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` - `si-shop-three.ttf` this font doesn't load and i'm not find the related css or `@font-face code`